# What does Mrs. Jones represent in Animal Farm?

Tags: symbolism, george-orwell, animal-farm

There are a few mentions of Mrs. Jones, primarily in reference to her table cloth. Does she represent something in and of herself? If so, what does Mrs. Jones represent in Animal Farm?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Orwell explicitly stated that the story of Animal Farm was a retelling of the Russian Revolution. Since the farm represents the "*Russian Imperial Regime*", by extension Farmer Jones is therefore Czar Nicholas II, which logically suggests that his wife, Mrs Jones is acting the part of **[Alexandra Feodorovna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandra_Feodorovna_(Alix_of_Hesse))**, Tsarina of Russia.

> **Orwell:** *After that, I wanted to do two things. First, I wanted to kill the "Russian myth:" the myth that the Soviet Union was a working
>   model of what a socialist state would be like. That was nothing but a
>   lie. **I wrote a history of the Russian Revolution and called it Animal
>   Farm.***
>
> *Of course, that book tells the story of how the animals rebel against
>   **the farmer who runs their farm -- the Russian imperial regime** -- how
>   they establish a revolution, and how the revolution is then gradually
>   subverted into a new class system in which the pigs, who are the
>   brains of the outfit, become a new, tyrannical ruling class. And the
>   animals find themselves in just as bad a situation as they were in
>   before.*
>
> <sub><sup>["1984: An Interview with George Orwell"](https://arcticcompass.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/aldous-huxley.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: "It's generally held [link to cliffnotes]". Cliffnotes is not a reputable source, nor is it a good measure of what is generally held.

Comment: So the wife of the Czar is a Tsarina? And I suppose the wife of a Tsar would be a Czarina?

Comment: @user14111 - The uses are interchangeable and both are merely westernised representations of a cyrillic character . So, yes.